# Halt in the while loop but the while loop should not halt

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop that has to continuously fetch event from a queue, however, in one of the if statement in the while loop, I need to wait for 10 minutes to execute next statement. What would be a good solution so the while loop does not halt.

Comment: A code sample would be very helpful

Comment: How about [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to spawn off a new [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for that portion of logic that involves the 10 minute wait, allowing your loop to continue uninterrupted.  Also consider using a [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) (which creates the Thread for you).

Comment: But this schedule task will still cause the while loop delay with specified time.

Comment: @KevinQ, no it won't.  From the Javadoc: "A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread."  You can fire off a TimerTask that will execute later, while allowing your loop to continue uninterrupted.